# how to pass interface in fragment throw adapter?

Tags: java, android

In Home Fragment

```
userListAdapter = new UserListAdapter(getActivity(), response.getTray(), ?);
                RVUserList.setAdapter(userListAdapter);
```

in Adapter

```
public UserListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TrayModel> list, UserListInterface listInterface) {
    this.context = context;
    this.trayModelArrayList = list;
    this.userListInterface = listInterface;
}
```

and also implement UserListInterface in fragment

Answer (score 0):

```
userListAdapter = new UserListAdapter(getActivity(), response.getTray(), new UserListInterface(){
// interface methods
});
RVUserList.setAdapter(userListAdapter);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
userListAdapter = new UserListAdapter(getActivity(), response.getTray(), HomeFragment.this::userListClick);
                RVUserList.setAdapter(userListAdapter);
```